# R metafor forest plot: change summary polygon size without changing annotation size

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I have a forest plot with sub-analyses where some of the summary estimates extend beyond the plot limits and end up cutting off summary annotations, making the plot look less than great. I don't want to change the plot limits because there are a set of study-level estimates that that have super wide CI's and a set that have reasonable CI's which I want to keep for being squeezed.

I tried variants of addpoly without finding a satisfactory solution, but perhaps someone has dealt with the case already:
`addpoly.rma(x=ma.time03, row = 1.5, transf=exp, mlab="", level=95, efac=0)`

Is there a method for shrinking just the summary polygon, but not the annotations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the size of the polygon by using the `efac` statement within the `addpoly.rma` or `forest` function.

For example try to set the `efac` statement <1 e.g. `efac = 0.5` or `efac = c(1,1,0.5)` if you want to make the polygon bigger, you can use values >1.